# Keywords not comprised in module's symbol table

Tags: python

I have such a drafts.py module:

```
import subprocess
print(globals())
```

Run it and get

```
In [77]: subprocess.getoutput('python drafts.py')
Out[77]: "{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': 
None, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x102c5a0b8>, 
'__spec__': None, 
'__annotations__': {}, 
'__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 
'__file__': 'drafts.py', 
'__cached__': None, 'subprocess': <module 'subprocess' from '/Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py'>}"
```

I could read from the result that `builtins` and `imported module` included in its symbol table,
However, the keywords are not involved in the symbol table.

If not comprised in module's symbol table, how could I employ them unlimited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean, but Python keywords are not symbols per se. They are processed by the parser directly, so they aren't looked up in any symbol table.